# Logic app doesn't trigger on function create

Tags: azure

I am currently trying to develop a microservice environment using [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/), a custom service registry and then a gateway for API calls.

I am currently trying to develop a method when new Function Apps are created in Azure (either by me or scaling) they register with my service repo. The service repo is a basic REST api that accepts POST's from the functions where they will register themselves.

Currently I have tried using an Azure [logic app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) with a custom trigger that triggers on:

> Microsoft.Resources.ResourceActionSuccess
>
> Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess

And then sends an HTTP POST to an endpoint for testing. The entire trigger and result looks as follows:
[image: Azure setup]

I can manually run the trigger and the portal and it successfully posts to the endpoint, but when I create a new function it doesn't. Does anyone possibly have any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I test with my resource group it could trigger the logic app. To reduce the impact of other actions, I add the `Prefix Filter` with `/subscriptions/subscription id/resourceGroups/group name/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.AppServiceFunctionAppCreate` and delete the `ResourceActionSuccess` event type cause create a function will have more than one action.

[image]

[image]

[image]

From your description, you already could trigger the logic app cause the event grid trigger is not a manual trigger, if it works means actually it could detect the actions in the group however maybe the actions are not the function creation. So you need add some filter or in the  logic app add some conditions.

Comment: It turned out that the eventgrid wasn't registered on my subscription. Once I registered the eventgrid it worked without a problem!

Comment: @Tachyon,If this could help you, you could accept it as the answer. Or if you have a better answer, you could post it and accept.